# Set up an integral for the circumference of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections

I've been given a problem, which I'm unsure whether I'm answering it right, and wondered if someone can take a look and tell me if I'm on the right track and any guidance would be appreciated.

**My Problem:**

Set up an integral that computes the circumference of an ellipse, but don't try to solve it as it is proven that the integral can't be solved. Where R is my radius.

**Solution:**

I know my integral should be something along the lines of: $$4\int_{0}^{R}\sqrt{a^{2}cos^{2}\theta+b^{2}sin^{2}\theta}d\theta$$

Is this along the right lines or am I meant to be using the formula: $$C=4aE(e)$$ where $e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}}$.

Any help and guidance on this would be great.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a path $\gamma$ is given by $\int_a^{b} |\gamma'(t)|dt$. Here $\gamma (t)=(a \sin \, t, b \cos \, t), 0\leq t \leq 2\pi$. Hence the length is $\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt {a^{2} \cos^{2}(t)+b^{2} \sin^{2}(t)} dt$.

Comment: Ok thank you, and that integral isn't solvable because it has the $a$ and $b$ variables inside the integral.  Is that right to say that?